# Show that the pair $(X,[-1,1])$ and $(Z,[-i,i])$ satisfy the Homotopy Extension Property.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

1. (Propoisition 0.17 - Hatcher) If the pair $(X,A)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property (HEP) and $A$ is contractible, then the quotient map $q: B \rightarrow B/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.
2. A pair $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property $\iff$ $X \times \{0\}  \cup A \times I$ is a retract of $X \times I $ (where $A$ is closed in $X$).

We want to show that the following are homotopy equivalent to each other:

[image]

Let's call them $X,Y$ and $Z$ respectively. We denote them mathmatically in the following manner:

In $\mathbb{C}$, we denote the circle $C_p$ with center at $p$ and radius $1$. Let $X=C_{-2} \cup C_{2} \cup [-1,1] \;, Y = C_{-1} \cup C_{1}$ and $Z = C_{0}\cup [-i,i]$. Comparing to (1), $A=[-1,1]$ in $X$ and $[-i,i]$ in $Z$.

Since, $[-1,1]$ and $[-i,i]$ both are contractible to a point, I wanted to use propositio (1) to show that $X$ and $Z$ are homotopy equivalent to $Y$:

(Q)How do I show that the pair $(X,[-1,1])$ and $(Z,[-i,i])$ satisfy the HEP using the property (2)?

Comment: If I am not wrong, for (2) to be true,  $A$ must be closed in $X$.

Comment: @LearningMath it is true without the assumption of closedness. It is more difficult to show, however. I believe that Hatcher has a proof in the appendix of his book.

Comment: There's a theorem in Hatcher's book that if $X$ is a CW complex and $A\subseteq X$ a subcomplex then $(X,A)$ has HEP. That's an easier approach.

Comment: I am not comfortable with cell complexes. So, I was hoping to solve without using cell complexes. I am guessing that you would give the construction of $X,Y,Z$ using cell complexes?